# Woocommerce drop down filter does not work on iOS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, wordpress, woocommerce

I am currently working on a client's woocommerce website/webshop and it is almost finished.

Except I'm experiencing a flaw/bug/name-it-what-you-want in one of my (standard) woocommerce layered nav widget. On any device: pc/android-tablet/android-phone it works but on any iOS device the (presumably) onchange action does not fire.

I have seen that my product sort order field is enclosed in a form called

```
<li class="woocommerce widget_layered_nav">

  <h2 class="widgettitle">  
    --TITLE (sort)--  
  </h2>

  <form class="woocommerce-ordering has-validation-callback" method="get">
    <select name="orderby" class="orderby">
    --Options (sort)--
    </select>
  </form>

</li>
```

And my other filters not

```
<li id="woocommerce_layered_nav-5" class="widget woocommerce widget_layered_nav">

  <h2 class="widgettitle">
    --Title (brands)--  
  </h2>

  <select class="dropdown_layered_nav_merk">
     --Options (brands)--
  </select>

</li>
```

Is there any workaround or fix for this issue?

Answer (score 3):

Try this. Enter the following code into your theme functions.php file:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'agentwp_dequeue_stylesandscripts', 100 );

function agentwp_dequeue_stylesandscripts() {
if ( class_exists( 'woocommerce' ) ) {
wp_dequeue_style( 'select2' );
wp_deregister_style( 'select2' );

wp_dequeue_script( 'select2');
wp_deregister_script('select2');

}
}
```

This simple bit of code will disable the enhanced boxes and give you a good old fashioned dropdown menu. This method has been tested in WooCommerce 2.5.5.